# Adding Glimpse plugin to project

Tags: c#, asp.net, glimpse

I'm trying to create a custom plugin for Glimpse. I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.i-m-code.com/blog/blog/2013/03/29/create-glimpse-plugin/)

I've referenced the assembly, built the project, and ran it, but I don't see a new tab. As a test I also tried installing this claims inspector [plugin](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.ClaimsInspector) via nuget, but that too doesn't seem to work.

What else do I have to do to get a tab to display?

**EDIT**

Here is the code

```
public class TestInspector: AspNetTab
{
    public override object GetData(ITabContext context)
    {
        var returnCollection = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        return returnCollection;
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "Test"; }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a plugin (project B) that is independent of the code in project A where project A would reference project B's assembly.

Having said that I've taken the code above and dropped it into a new class in project A and I do see the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the new project was using .NET 4.5 and the project that was referencing it was 4.0. Updated the project and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the tab that you have created? That will help figure out the problem.

In general through, **all** tabs in Glimpse are plugins - including the ones that come with the Glimpse NuGet package, so it seems that some are being picked up but not others.

A few troubleshooting tips:

- Check your `bin` folder and make sure the extension assembly is there
- Make sure your extension class is `public`
- [Turn on logging](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration). Glimpse will tell you what any loading exceptions it may of had.
- Restart your web server

Comment: Apparently the assembly isn't getting loaded.